# Twitter API Authorisation problem - 401 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm having trouble getting a call to the Twitter API working. 
I'm having to do this as the package i was using has got an issue and the fix isn't compatible with my project.

I want to retrieve a list of 'recent' tweets but I keep getting a 401. I have a feeling it is because of the way I'm creating my signature but I'm not certain.

My request URL is:

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?result_type=recent&count=1&q=#hashtag1 OR #hashtag2 OR #hashtag3`

I have the following auth info:

```
Dictionary<string, object> _parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
_parameters.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");
_parameters.Add("oauth_nonce", "[VALUE]");
_parameters.Add("oauth_timestamp", [TIMESTAMP]);
_parameters.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
_parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_key", "[VALUE]");
_parameters.Add("oauth_consumer_secret", "[VALUE]");
_parameters.Add("oauth_token", "[VALUE]");
_parameters.Add("oauth_token_secret", "[VALUE]");
```

My 'create signature' method is as follows. It uses the full URL with search parameters to construct it:

```
    private static string GenerateSignature(Dictionary<string,object> parameters, Uri requestUri, string consumerSecret, string accessTokenSecret)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> nonSecretParameters;

        nonSecretParameters = (from p in parameters
                               where (!SecretParameters.Contains(p.Key))
                               select p);

        Uri urlForSigning = requestUri;

        string signatureBaseString = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}&{1}&{2}",
            "GET",
            UrlEncode(NormalizeUrl(urlForSigning)),
            UrlEncode(nonSecretParameters));

        string key = string.Format(
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "{0}&{1}",
            UrlEncode(consumerSecret),
            UrlEncode(accessTokenSecret));

        HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        byte[] signatureBytes = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureBaseString));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
    }

    private static string UrlEncode(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        value = Uri.EscapeDataString(value);

        value = Regex.Replace(value, "(%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])", c => c.Value.ToUpper());

        value = value
            .Replace("(", "%28")
            .Replace(")", "%29")
            .Replace("$", "%24")
            .Replace("!", "%21")
            .Replace("*", "%2A")
            .Replace("'", "%27");

        value = value.Replace("%7E", "~");

        return value;
    }

    private static string NormalizeUrl(Uri url)
    {
        string normalizedUrl = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}://{1}", url.Scheme, url.Host);
        if (!((url.Scheme == "http" && url.Port == 80) || (url.Scheme == "https" && url.Port == 443)))
        {
            normalizedUrl += ":" + url.Port;
        }

        normalizedUrl += url.PathAndQuery + url.Fragment.Replace("%20", " ");
        return normalizedUrl;
    }
```

Once I have the signature, I generate my `Authorisation` header which is something like this:
`OAuth oauth_consumer_key="[VALUE]",oauth_nonce="[VALUE]",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1565261231",oauth_token="[VALUE]",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="[VALUE]"`

Then I append the relevant auth params to the URL and make the request to the Twitter API. The final URL is something like this:
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?result_type=recent&count=1&q=%23hashtag1 OR %23hashtag2 OR %23hashtag3`

Comment: One way to debug is getting this to work via Twurl and compare the headers this code generates against twurls

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at that. I think it is something specific to my signature or maybe the flow i have is wrong....not sure